# when I enter my website address it show me PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, webserver

I'm configured my wordpress website in ubuntu ec2 instance, but when i enter my website adresse, it display this code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

please any one can help me, thank you.

Comment: Did you follow this https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/ ?

Comment: Hi, no because i have already a wordpress site, just i want to put it in ec2 instant

Comment: Maybe one of these than sorry I don't use wordpress with AWS,,,, https://www.onepagezen.com/migrate-wordpress-aws/ or https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/migrate-your-wordpress-blog-to-amazon-lightsail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays this code *in the browser*? That means that you haven't installed / configured PHP on your server.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is whether the web server is working. You can do this by connecting to the EC2 instance via SSH and running:

```
curl localhost
```

If this does *not* return a page, then you will need to investigate and fix your web server.

Next thing to check is networking. Check the configuration of the **Security Group** associated with the EC2 instance. It needs to permit HTTP (port 80) and possibly HTTPS (port 443) from `0.0.0.0/0`.

In fact, a quick way to figure out whether the problem is network-related is to see **how long the page takes before it fails**. If it fails immediately, then it means that the request was received by the instance but rejected. If, instead, it takes a few seconds before it fails, this indicates that the request was never received and therefore the problem lies somewhere in the network configuration or security group.

You mention that you "enter my website address". You should be first testing that the connection works by using the **IP address**. Once that is working, you can test with any DNS names you have associated to the instance.

Comment: Thank you @Jhon, for the Security Group is good, and for the curl localhost return :
```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
  <table>
...
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```
how long the page takes before it fails : it fails immediately.

and the PHP is already installed

Comment: What happens if you go to to IP address in your browser? (eg `http://54.11.22.33`)

Comment: What do you mean by "fails immediately"? Does it give an error, or does it display the PHP code you have in your question? If it displays the PHP code, then it means your web server has not been configured to handle PHP. However, your `curl` command is showing `Index of /`, which also suggests that the web server has not been configured to default to your `index.php` page.